# Error in autocomplete in rails if the name is having spaces in between and multiple auto complete in the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

HI ,

I am using Auto complete in rails .

My auto complete looks like

```
          <%= text_field_with_auto_complete User.name, :login, { :size => 15 }, { :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'autocomplete_for_supervisors'}, :method => :get, :param_name => 'term'} %>
```

This generates the fields where

```
     <input type="text"  size="15" name="Franklin Roosevl[login]" id="Franklin_Roosevl_login">
     <div id="Franklin Roosevl_login_auto_complete" class="auto_complete"></div>
```

This doesnt allows me to do auto complete .
But if my Username is a single name its working perfectly
How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you naming your text field with User.name??

Maybe you should try this:

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :user, :login, { :size => 15 }, { :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'autocomplete_for_supervisors'}, :method => :get, :param_name => 'term'} %>
```

Comment: i have many auto completes in the page for different users/. so i am keeping id as username[login]. In some cases username is having 2 words which is causing troubles and auto complete is not working in that cases.

Comment: so go with user_123[login], where 123 is user's id: <%= text_field_with_auto_complete "user_#{User.id}", :login, { :size => 15 }, { :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'autocomplete_for_supervisors'}, :method => :get, :param_name => 'term'} %>